# SQL query for finding all tables ROWS with two columns in them

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a DataBase with around +100 tables, like half of tables have column A & column B.

My question is, Can I query all tables that have this columns with a specific values e.g.

> SELECT * FROM DATABASE
>
> WHERE
>
> EACHTABLE HAS COLUMN A = 21    //only if table has columns and then values
>
> AND
>
> COLUMN B = 13

I am not sure how exact I will do it, nothing is coming up on google either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the undocumented MS stored procedure `sp_MSforeachtable`, if you fancy living life recklessly:

```
create table T1 (
    ColumnA int not null,
    ColumnB int not null
)
go
create table T2 (
    ColumnA int not null,
    Column2 int not null
)
go
create table T3 (
    Column1 int not null,
    ColumnB int not null
)
go
create table T4 (
    ColumnA int not null,
    ColumnB int not null
)
go
insert into T1 values (1,2);
insert into T2 values (3,4);
insert into T3 values (5,6);
insert into T4 values (7,8);
go
create table #Results (TableName sysname,ColumnA int,ColumnB int)
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'insert into #Results select ''?'',ColumnA,ColumnB from ?',
    @whereand = ' and syso.object_id in (select object_id from sys.columns where name=''ColumnA'') and syso.object_id in (select object_id from sys.columns where name=''ColumnB'')'
select * from #Results
drop table #Results
```

Result:

```
TableName                             ColumnA     ColumnB
------------------------------------- ----------- -----------
[dbo].[T1]                            1           2
[dbo].[T4]                            7           8
```

---

By default, `sp_MSforeachtable` will, as its name implies, perform the same task for each table in the database. However, one optional parameter to this procedure, called `@Whereand`, can be used to modify the `WHERE` clause of the internal query that enumerates the tables in the database. It helps to know that this internal query has already established two aliases to some of the system views. `o` is an alias for `sysobjects` (the legacy system view). `syso` is an alias for `sys.all_objects` (a more modern system view).

Once `sp_MSforeachtable` has decided which tables to run against, it will execute the query given to it as its first parameter. But, it will replace `?` with the schema and table name (`?` is the default replacement character. This can be changed as needed)

In this case, I chose to create a temp table, then have each selected table store its results into this temp table, and after `sp_MSforeachtable` has finished running, to select the combined results out with no further processing.

There is a similar (and similarly undocumented) procedure called `sp_MSforeachdb` which will access each user database on the server. These can even be combined (although you have to be careful with doubling up `'` quote characters twice, at times). However, there's no equivalent `sp_MSforeachcolumn`.

Comment: Can you please explain the part where your executing it :)

and also

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967030/query-to-find-and-replace-a-specific-text-in-sql-database-all-tables-and-all-co/11967214#11967214

Comment: and also , how can I filter Scheme ID with a specific number :) and last thing , why we are creating  4 tables with random data in them first

Comment: @fdgfdgsdfg - I've added a bit of explanation. And I created the four tables because I needed some example tables to work with - you didn't provide any in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 select t.name from sys.objects t inner join sys.columns c
 on t.name=OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id)
 where t.type='U'
 and c.name in('col1','col2')
 group by t.name
 having COUNT(*) = 2
 order by 1
```

Then you just loop through all the tables and fine the values for these columns.

Like

```
Declare @out TABLE(tblname varchar(100))
if exists(select * from tbl1 where col1='21' and col2='22')
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @out
select tbl1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this using dynamic query.

```
select 'select * from '+table_name+ ' where'+column_name+'=21'
from information_schema.columns where column_name = 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use two steps:
First, find out all tables in your database that have these two columns and use it for a temporal derived table. For I am not an expert in SQL-Server 2008 I recommend to have a look at the whitepages.

The expression **might** look like this:

```
SELECT tablename
FROM information_schema.tables sdbt
WHERE "column a" IN
    (SELECT columns
     FROM information_schema.columns col
     WHERE col.tablename = sdbt.tablename)
```

Second, use a expresssion to filter the results according to your demanded values.

Comment: The important thing to remember about the information_schema database is that you can query it, but you cannot change its structure or modify its data.

http://kb.siteground.com/article/What_is_the_information_schema_database.html

Answer (score 0):

This command should do the trick in one go, only for column A, amend accordingly to include any other columns you need:

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable
@command1=N'SELECT * FROM ? WHERE A = 21',
@whereand=' and o.name IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = ''A'') '
```