# Query to find and replace a specific text in SQL Database (All tables and All Columns)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a DB with +100 tables, most tables have a column that saves a URL but with different "Column Name" and URL is different as well. e.g.

In one table its

```
usa3030.Development.com/portal/mybook/chapter1/page1/line1
```

and in another one its

```
usa3030.Development.com/portal/mybook/chapter1
```

and so on, but for sure each URL have "usa3030.Development.com/portal/mybook/chapter1" in them

**So I want a query that Will find each column that have text within column data (with "*" I think we call wildcard)**

```
"usa3030.Development.com/portal/mybook/chapter1"
```

and replace it with

```
usa3030.Development.com/MyWorld/Chp1
```

**Answer**

[Search Or replace Stored Procedure](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I guess you have to go through the following steps:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(max)
For each table in sys.Objects (where type='U')

      For each column of the above table

        IF EXISTS(select * from tablename where colname like '%'+@string+'%')
        update table tablename SET colnmae=REPLACE(colname,'old','new') where colname like '%'+@string+'%')
```